# To fill the 0's with before 3 months average value using python

Tags: python, pandas

My data set has values like

```
date           quantity
01/04/2018        35
01/05/2018        33
01/06/2018        75
01/07/2018         0
01/08/2018        70
01/09/2018         0
01/10/2018        66
```

Code I tried:

```
df['rollmean3']  = df['quantity'].rolling(3).mean()
```

output:

```
2018-04-01  35.0    NaN
2018-05-01  33.0    NaN
2018-06-01  75.0    47.666667
2018-07-01  0.0     36.000000
2018-08-01  70.0    48.333333
2018-09-01  0.0     23.333333
2018-10-01  66.0    45.333333
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
But I need output as it should take the AVERAGE of 35,33 and 75 and fill it in the 0.0 value.
and for next zero it should calculated average for previous three values and fill it.

```
2018-04-01  35.0    
2018-05-01  33.0    
2018-06-01  75.0    
2018-07-01  0.0     47.666667
2018-08-01  70.0    
2018-09-01  0.0     64.22222 # average of (0, 47.6667 and 75)
2018-10-01  66.0
```

like this output should be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like John Zwinck said, there's no vectorized solution in pandas for this.

You'll have to use something like `.itterrows()`, like this:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['quantity'] == 0:
        df.loc[i,'quantity'] = df['quantity'].iloc[(i-3):i].mean()
```

Or even with recursion, if you prefer:

```
def fill_recursively(column: pd.Series, window_size: int = 3):
    if 0 in column.values:
        idx = column.tolist().index(0)
        column[idx] = column[(idx-window_size):idx].mean()
        column = fill_recursively(column)
    return column
```

You can verify that `fill_recursively(df['quantity'])` returns the desired result (just make sure that it has the dtype float, otherwise it will be rounded to the nearest integer).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a vectorized solution for this in Pandas.  You'll need to iterate the rows and fill in the missing values one by one.  This will be slow; if you need to speed it up you can JIT compile your code using [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).